# JMeter distributed load testing - Master in local system and slave in AWS EC2 windows instance - not able to connect

Tags: jmeter

I'm running my Master Jmeter in my local laptop and created Slave in AWS EC2 Windows instance. I have set up the IP address of the EC2 in my master Jmeter properties file.
I also made sure that both the master and slave are having the same JMeter Version.
Now when i connect slave through gui or non gui mode i'm getting the below error.
Please help me resolve this.

```
14:52:23,294 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.ActionRouter: Error processing org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart@5b22b970
java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[172.31.3.238]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into `172.31.3.238` address it seems you are trying to connect the [private address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) of your AWS instance and you should be using the [Public IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#using-instance-addressing-common) instead.

Also make sure that the relevant port `1099` by default is exposed via [AWS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-network-security.html) and your [Windows firewall](https://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=19320).

Also consider moving your `master` instance to AWS as well, otherwise you might get huge bills for the traffic which is free between AWS instances in the same region. See [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) for more information on setting up the connectivity between master and slaves.

Answer (score 0):

When u create master/Slave relationship it is preferred to have both the machines in the same vlan so that there shouldn't be any communication issue, try to have them in same vlan and the check it..!!